# optional<reference_wrapper<T>> vs. optional<T>& - practical examples?

Tags: c++, reference, c++17, option-type

I have read about `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>>` as a way to pass around optional references.

However, I'm unable to think of a practical example where I'd do that, instead of just using an `optional<T>&`.

For example, suppose I'm writing a function which needs to take an optional `vector<int>` by reference.

I could do this:

```
void f(optional<reference_wrapper<vector<int>>> v) {
    // ...
}

int main() {
    vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    f(make_optional<reference_wrapper<vector<int>>>(std::ref(v));
    return 0;
}
```

But why not just do this?

```
void f(optional<vector<int>>& v) {
    // ...
}

int main() {
    f(make_optional<vector<int>>>(std::initializer_list{1, 2, 3, 4}));
    return 0;
}
```

Please give an example where `optional<reference_wrapper<T>>` is preferable to `optional<T>&`. The semantic differences, and especially the ways they can be leveraged in practice aren't clear to me.

Comment: Think of return values. The `optional` would be a temporary variable being returned.

Comment: When are you in a situation where you're picking between those two? They mean different things... use the one that means the relevant thing for the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::optional<T> &` is a reference to an optional object that can own a `T` object.  You can mutate a `T` (if one is contained) or you can clear the optional object that was passed in by reference, destroying the contained `T`.

---

`std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>>` is an optional object that can own a reference to a `T`, *but it doesn't actually own the `T` itself.* The `T` lives *outside* of the `std::optional` object.  You can mutate the `T` (if a reference is contained) or you can clear the optional object, which does *not* destroy the `T`.  You can also make the optional object point at a different `T`, but this would be kind of pointless since the caller is passing you an optional *by value.*

Note that we *already* have a type built-in to the language that means "optional reference to a `T`": `T*`.  Both a raw pointer and an optional reference have basically the same semantics: you either get nothing or you get a handle to an object you don't own. In modern C++, a raw pointer is the way to express an optional value not owned by the receiver.

I can't think of a single reason I'd ever explicitly use `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>>` instead of `T*`.

Comment: I see - `optional<T>& x = ...` forces lifetime ownership of `x` over the `T` object, meaning if we already have a `T` object, we must copy it inside `x`. `optional<reference_wrapper<T>>&` doesn't own the `T` object, because `reference_wrapper<T>` doesn't own the `T` object, thus it can be used when we already have an existing `T` object (but in that case, might as well use a bare `T*`). All clear, thanks.

Comment: @AvivCohn Yep, that's exactly it!

Answer (score 2):

> But why not just do this?

Because your code doesn't compile. `make_optional` returns a prvalue, and you cannot pass a prvalue to a function that takes a non-`const` lvalue reference.

That's important because it shows the fundamental difference between these two cases. If you already have a `T` or a reference to a `T` from somewhere else, then you *cannot* pass that to a function that takes an `optional<T>&`. You'd have to copy the `T` into an `optional<T>` variable, then pass a reference to the `optional` variable to the function.

You wouldn't be able to modify the outside world's `T`. And that's the difference: with `reference_wrapper<T>`, you could.

Or if you have a function that can work with or without a modifiable `T`, you could just pass a `T*` like most people would.

Comment: I see - it's a question of ownership. `optional<T>` owns the lifetime of the `T` object (and `optional<T>&` is just a reference to an `optional<T>`, while `optional<reference_wrapper<T>>` owns the lifetime of the `reference_wrapper<T>`, which does *not* own the lifetime of the `T` object. Thus the different semantics. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers state, the two types serve different purposes, as the reference is to different things (a reference to an `optional` in one case and a reference to a `vector` in the other). Rather than repeating the explanation, here is some code you can play with to see the functional differences.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <optional>


// For better readability:
using optional_reference_vector = std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<int>>>;
using optional_vector           = std::optional<std::vector<int>>;


void f(optional_reference_vector v) {
    v->get().push_back(5);
}

void g(optional_vector & w) {
    w->push_back(5);
}

int main() {
    // Two identical vectors with which to work:
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::vector<int> w = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    // Demonstrate an optional reference to a vector
    // ---------------------------------------------
    // Create a reference to `v` in `opt_v`.
    // Changes to `opt_v` will be reflected in `v` (and vice versa).
    optional_reference_vector opt_v {std::ref(v)};
    v.clear();
    // A copy of `opt_v` will be made in f(). Since we are copying a reference to
    // a vector and not the vector itself, the vector in main() is changed by f().
    f(opt_v);
    // Both `v` and `opt_v` refer to the same vector, so the size is the same.
    std::cout << "Using a reference to the vector:\n"
              << "Original vector size: " << v.size() << '\n'
              << "Optional vector size: " << opt_v->get().size() << "\n\n";

    // Demonstrate a reference to an optional vector
    // ---------------------------------------------
    // Copy `w` into `opt_w`.
    // Changes to `opt_w` have no effect on `w` (and vice versa).
    optional_vector opt_w {w};
    w.clear();
    // A reference to `opt_w` will be used in g(), so `opt_w` is updated.
    g(opt_w);
    // There are two vectors that now have different sizes.
    std::cout << "Using a copy of the vector:\n"
              << "Original vector size: " << w.size() << '\n'
              << "Optional vector size: " << opt_w->size() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The output from this code:

```
Using a reference to the vector:
Original vector size: 1
Optional vector size: 1

Using a copy of the vector:
Original vector size: 0
Optional vector size: 5
```